# flash message if user is not login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

When user tried to go user dashboard without login, it return to login page. it works perfectly. but I need to show message on login page using middleware that 'please login to see this page.'

I tried {!! $errors->first('loginpermission', ':message') !!}

But it not working

Please help me how to use this.

Comment: Please show how you're protecting your route from unauthorized access.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: First of all. ``{{ $errors->first('loginpermission') }}``. Maybe you don't return message?

Answer (score 1):

Add these codes in your login.blade page

```
@if (session('status'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('status') }}
</div>
@endif
@if (session('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ session('error') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Add below code in your middleware at condition when user is not logged in

```
return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'please login to your account');
```

Comment: My problem was that I was using redirect(url('')) rather than simply specifying the route

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ($errors->has('loginpermission'))
 {{ $errors->first('loginpermission') }}
@endif
```

Comment: This has got nothing to do with the original problem statement

Comment: @LordWilmore why not? It basically checks the key in the errors array before using the value. Even though it's a code only answer, it's related to the OP's code.

Comment: Your suggestion is to check whether the user has login permission before attempting to get the value, which is fine.  But the OP's question was to perform some action if the user has the permission to log in, i.e. ' I need to show message on login page using middleware that 'please login to see this page.', and they were stuck on _that_ part, not the check